# model time series with logistic growth and decay with fbprohet

Tags: r, time-series, modeling

My time series looks like this:

[image]

Is fbprohet suitable for this kind of time series or would I be better of using exponential smoothing (e.g. holt) in R?

I know how to use logistic rather than linear in fbprohet (mainly R) but the output does not get a nice decay after the change-point.

Can I use fbprohet for this and if so which hyper parameters would I have to tune/are the most important ones?

Comment: Why do you want to use Prophet in here? What exactly do you want to achieve (forecasting with this data is rather hopeless)?

Comment: sorry why is it hopeless? maybe I did not make this clear but the decay is assumed and has not fully materialized ...

Comment: You have no seasonality, no cycles in here, so the only possible forecast is either flat, or something like a downward line, but we have no way o knowing what would be correct in here, since in the past nothing like this has happened in your data.

Comment: thanks. but let us say there was an impulse of input previously, which led to the logistic growth. But the impulse was switched of hence the decay. In fbprohet I can use add regressor to model this. However, maybe this is some basic regression problem ...

Comment: You wouldn't use most of the functionality of Prophet in here, you would only use piecewise regression, and you don't need Prophet for this.